# Gift option in cart instead of shipping block on checkout?

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, magento-enterprise, onepage-checkout

I'm trying to accomplish this without an additional extension. I am including the checkout process on my cart page and would like to move the gift option in the cart section with the ability for each product to have it's own checkbox that asks if this is a gift.

The way it's set up currently it doesn't look like I can easily integrate it the way I would like.

Has anyone else done this that can give me some pointers?

Comment: You would need to create a custom extension for this and modify a few of the `app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/checkout/*` files to get started.  Have you attempted anything yet?

Comment: Is your question applicable to both Mage 1.7 CE AND Mage EE? if this is not an extension I would expect the store to be one of both.

Comment: Given that you are including / want to include "the checkout process on [your] cart page" you *are* writing an extension, and a complicated one at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without writing an extension. To do this it would involve, at least on Mage 1.7, adding a field either in the order object or on the order item level.

By default all order items is either gift wrapped or none of them are so this new field should specify exactly which products are gift wrapped.

This data would also need to be displayed in all order grids, emails, PDF's, custom account orders. Doing this without writing a custom extension for it would result in a lot of phtml files and core classes being modified.